# Bootstrap4 Navbar collapse overflows. Express/Node partial

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, bootstrap-4

below is a picture of an issue I'm having with the navbar collapse from bootstrap. I'm running express, node, and handlebars. This header is a partial. For some reason, it keeps expanding outside of its div and I cant figure out why.
 [navbar collapse overflow problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIZWi.png)

Here are my two pages of code for the main page and the header partial. On home.hbs I'm using a CSS grid, not sure if that's causing it or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components-font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="contentContainer">
          <div class="navMenu">
            {{> header}}
          </div>
          <div class="sidebarLeft">
            <!--Add sidebarLeft variable for navigation -->
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div>
              <p class="welcome"> Welcome to my portfolio page. </p>
              <p class="clickBelow"> I've been learning Javascript, Python, and Spanish for 7 months
            while living abroad in Mexico.</p>
            <div class="buttonDiv">
              <button class="enter" size="lg">Come take a look</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebarRight">
            <!--Add sidebarRight variable for navigation -->
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            {{> footer}}
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
    <script src="/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
</html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/components-font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css" />
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top container-flui">
  <a class-"navbar-brand" href="/">Steven</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Anyone know? I've tried adding container-fluid to multiple divs. It appears that jquery and bootstrap are working. I've installed these through bower.

Comment: I had an issue where my page content was being overlapped by the navbar, try removing the fixed-top property.

Comment: You are the man, Geet! Thanks so much. I could not figure out what was wrong. 

It's always something small, haha. Thanks again.

Comment: Haha no problem. May be upvote the comment?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm a stackoverflow noob... it doesn't show any option for upvoting your comment. Am I missing something?

Comment: You will need more reputation for upvoting comments, just mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue where my page content was being overlapped by the navbar, try removing the fixed-top property.